# Have a single list of Integers and need to divide it into two separate lists where the sum of the integers in both lists are equal or close to equal

Tags: algorithm, list, arraylist

I am brand new to the computer science field. I'm hoping to land my first job in the field. It's a  Salesforce internship here in SF and I was given this problem to figure out. I'm not really sure where to begin. Any help or just pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you and Happy Holidays.

Here is the problem:
Consider a scenario where you have a single list of integers and need to divide it into two separate lists where the sum of the integers in both lists are equal or close to equal. Each sublist must have at least one element. Please describe two approaches to solving this problem. The first approach should use an algorithm that is accurate and the second approach should use an algorithm that is faster. To clarify, our definition of accurate means "guaranteed to find the best possible answer that meets our requirements". For the faster solution, we still expect your algorithm to find a correct answer most of the time. The algorithms should not have the same Big-O notation.

Comment: This is a special case of the knapsack problem where all values are equal. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Have you written any code to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Approximate algorithm with O(n log-n) complexity:

1. Sort the list in descending order (complexity O(n log-n));
2. Place the items of the sorted list in two piles, so that as each item is placed the difference between the sum of the two lists is minimized (complexity O(n)).

Exact solution with complexity (2^n):

1. Using the bits of every integer from 0 to 2^n as a bit mask for
   inclusion in list 1, exhaustively test every possible assignment of
   the list members to the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stupid simple solution to your problem that may get close to the best answer, but is not guaranteed to. This is a c# version, i don't know what language you are doing it in.

I'll leave it to you to find a version that is guaranteed to get the best answer.

```
public void SplitLists()
{
    var numbers = new int[100];
    var ran = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i ++)
    {
        numbers[i] = ran.Next(10) + 1;
    }

    var list1 = new List<int>();
    var list2 = new List<int>();

    foreach (var num in numbers)
    {
        if(list1.Sum() + num < list2.Sum())
            list1.Add(num);
        else
            list2.Add(num);
    }
}
```